# Create grid then color it following given scenario in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a grid and color some cells sequentially so that the user can see cells turning on.

For the moment I have:

```
from tkinter import *

center=Tk()
center.geometry('455x455')
center.title("9x9 grid")

cells = {}
for row in range(9):
     for column in range(9):
        cell = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black",
                     highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1,
                     width=50, height=50,  padx=3,  pady=3)
        cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
        cells[(row, column)] = cell

def color_cell(cells, i, j, color="red"):
    cells[(i,j)].configure(background=color)

center.after(5000, color_cell(cells, 3, 4))

center.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I wait 5000ms before seeing everything. I want to see first the blank grid and then after 5000ms one of the cells turn red. End goal is to being able to illustrate a percolation algorithm (so the visualization has to be efficient). For the moment I chose Tkinter but that might be overkill, if you have a simpler alternative I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: first of you should see everything immediately, second, only one cell would be colored, also you don't use the arguments for the function, it does require them, but they are  not used whatsoever. I would suggest that you have a list/tuple that contains the order in which the cells will be colored for example `path = ((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), ...)` and so on, then make it an iterable and in an `after` loop, configure the `next` cell. Other library that I could suggest is `pygame` in terms of simplicity because it is kinda lower level, but I think `tkinter` is great fit for this too

Comment: about waiting, well, `after` does block `mainloop` if no callable is provided, and in your case `color_cell` returns `None` so it blocks for 5000ms, also did you mean to use `padx` and `pady` on the `grid` method?

Comment: Should `cells[(i,j)].configure(background="red")` be `cells[(i,j)].configure(background=color)` inside `color_cell()`?

Comment: yes you're right I made a mistake, I'm updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you call `color_cell` in `center.after()` instead of passing a reference to the function. You must do: `center.after(5000, color_cell, cells, 3, 4)`:

```
center = Tk()
center.geometry('455x455')
center.title("9x9 grid")

cells = {}
for row in range(9):
     for column in range(9):
        cell = Frame(center, bg='white', highlightbackground="black",
                     highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1,
                     width=50, height=50, padx=3, pady=3)
        cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
        cells[(row, column)] = cell


def color_cell(cells, i, j, color="red"):
    cells[(i, j)].configure(background="red")


center.after(5000, color_cell, cells, 3, 4)

center.mainloop()
```